# Where in the Bible does God permit us to create? How would science fit into this?

Tags: bible, creation, will-of-god

Its was a christian doctrine that we are pro-creators. So technically, we can build or create something.

However, I am a bit confused when some religious people curse science as "messing with God's creation". Like science is "creation of knowledge", "creation of tools", in fact almost "creation of anything"!

So these are my curious questions:

- Are we permitted to do this? Where can we find it that was messing with God?
- If otherwise, where can we find that God permits us to do this? Or does not restrict us to do this?

Comment: Why do you think God does not want us to create? He explicitly commands us to create altars, buildings, cities.

Comment: Which Christian doctrine says "we are pro-creators?  Can you please explain what you mean and provide some evidence to support your opening statement.

Comment: That is just what we were thought in several religion lessons. I am not a theologian so my usage of term might be wrong. If you may, I would be glad of you enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

To procreate is to reproduce. To procreate is a more formal way of saying "making babies".

In Genesis 1:28 God told man "be fruitful and multiply". To multiply is to procreate.

But is procreating "creating"?
  Suppose someone "creates" a loud noise because a heavy weight is dropped on their foot. In this instance they make something on the basis of how they were made. They shriek because they can't help it. Their shriek is an expression of who they are.
   Suppose the heavy weight was dropped by someone who was only expressing their nurture and nature, neither of which they chose.

Then these people could be instruments showing in their actions how God made them.
In this picture of human behaviour nobody creates in the sense that nothing originates in them. All their actions are just links in a chain of cause and effect. If all our actions [including having babies] are just links in a chain of cause and effect, a chain created and sustained by God who created and sustains all things [John 1:3 and Hebrews 1:3] then our lives are determined by God [This is called determinism].

Some object to determinism on the grounds that it makes God the creator of good and evil. Romans 9:21 talks of a potter who makes vessels of honour and vessels for dishonourable use. i.e. God having a holy motive for creating that which is, and that which is not, given the honour of obeying God's instructions to His church.

It appears to me that there are Christians who are:

Libertarians who put all human behaviour down to free will in which we create our ideas and behaviour.

Determinists who believe nothing ultimately originates in us and that judgement is having to live with the consequences of how we were made.

Compatibilists who think the Bible teaches free will and determinism, and that we must have faith to cope with this apparent contradiction.

This is not a full answer to your questioning but gives words and ideas for you to further explore.